# Show checkbox when user selects specific combobox option

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to Salesforce but I have basic JS and HTML knowledge. I am stuck trying to figure out how to only show a checkbox when a certain combobox (dropdown) value is selected. I already did that by using  and a handler for that specific element like this:

```
<lightning-combobox
            name="tipStudija"
            label="Tip študija"
            options={statusOptions}
            onchange={changeHandlerShowPlacnik}
            >
        </lightning-combobox>

changeHandlerShowPlacnik(event) {
    this.tipStudija = event.target.value;
    if (this.tipStudija === 'studij-izredni') {
        this.izredniPlacnik = true;
    }
}
```

But then I had to change the entire code when I discovered , which I have to use to easily move the data into the DB. I have no idea how to make this work now because I can't insert a handler where I need to and I don't know how to get the value from the form as it's put in. I have been googling for days and I tried everything that came up in search. This is the last thing I managed to put together and I can't even get the checkmark to not appear when I set the boolean to false. Never mind figuring out how to get the value from TIP_STUDIJA_FIELD on change.

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-record-form
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        fields={fields}
        onsuccess={handleSuccessNewSudent}>

        <template lwc:if={izredniPlacnik}>
            <lightning-input-field
                field-name={checkboxFieldApiName}>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </template>
    </lightning-record-form>
</lightning-card>
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import STUDENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c';
import FIRST_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.Ime_student__c';
import LAST_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.Priimek_student__c';
import EMSO_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.Emso__c';
import PREDMET_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.Predmet__c';
import TIP_STUDIJA_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.Tip_studija__c';
import STUDIJSKA_SMER_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.Studijska_smer__c';
import PLACNIK_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.Placnik__c';

export default class InputStudent2 extends LightningElement {
    objectApiName = STUDENT_OBJECT;
    checkboxFieldApiName = PLACNIK_FIELD
    izredniPlacnik = false;
    fields = [FIRST_NAME_FIELD, LAST_NAME_FIELD, EMSO_FIELD, PREDMET_FIELD, TIP_STUDIJA_FIELD, STUDIJSKA_SMER_FIELD, PLACNIK_FIELD];

    
/*     get izredniPlacnik () {
        return this.fields.Tip_studija__c.value === 'Izredni';
    }
 
    get checkboxFieldName() {
        return this.fields.Placnik__c.fieldApiName;
    } */

    handleSuccessNewSudent(event) {
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Account created",
            message: "Record ID: " + event.detail.id,
            variant: "success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
    }
}
```